# Edit the field of a contact

Tags: contacts, editing

is it possible to edit the field of a contact ("home", "work", "mobile", etc.)? 
I don't mean *the content* of the field, but the name OF THE FIELD ITSELF. I know it's not possible with the default app, so the question is: is there an app that allows you to do it?

Thanks,
Luke

Comment: You can add custom fields.  Is that not what you want?

Comment: A custom field would solve this in the easiest way, I'd agree with @rrirower on that. Otherwise I guess you could install some 3rd party contacts applications and see if they allow flexibility. I've never seen the option to change the labels, just add my own ones. I'd hazard a guess that "home, mobile, work" are kept generic so that a contact is standardised to some degree across devices / databases.

Comment: I have Android 4.4.2 and I can't add custom fields.